# Is it possible to build stand alone application which can interact with ethereum client and block chain?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am trying to develop a stand alone application in c++ using the c++ libraries provided for building cpp-ethereum client (http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html), is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but there is intentionally NOT any published C++ API for cpp-ethereum.

The published API is the JSON-RPC APIs and the command-line.  Anything else is subject to change-at-will.  We have been spending months reorganizing the code back into the cpp-ethereum repository, and the library boundaries within those are likely to change a lot too.

Other clients, like geth and Ethereum(J), are creating native APIs which sound like the kind of type which you are looking for.

Such APIs are not currently planned for cpp-ethereum, though maybe we will get there later.  For now you are best sticking at the JSON-RPC level, which will have the nice side-effect of keeping you largely client-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

It is easiest if you use NodeJS/JavaScript as there is an [official Ethereum API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) intended to make your life easier.

But you can use any language, you just connect to nodes using [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC).

Answer (score 0):

Its my understanding that Ethereum uses mostly opensource libraries that you would be open to use for your own projects but it would be best to check the libraries licenses to make clear any limitations.